# MVC html.dropdownlistfor not updating model field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I searched online and I think my code should be correct but when you submit the model field is always 0.
Model:

```
 public class ProductsModel
    {
        public List<Products> ProductCommission;
        public List<ProductGroupType> ProductGroupType;
        public  CommissionType CommissionType;
        public int FilterProductGroupTypeId;
        public string Status;

    }
```

View:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.FilterProductGroupTypeId, new SelectList(Model.ProductGroupType, "ID", "Description"), "All")
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.FilterProductGroupTypeId);
      @*  @Html.ActionLink("Filter", "FilterProductTypes", "Products", new { filterid = Model.FilterProductGroupTypeId });*@
 <a href="@Url.Action("FilterProductTypes", "Products", new { filterid  = Model.FilterProductGroupTypeId})">Filter</a>
```

Controller:

```
 public ViewResult FilterProductTypes(int filterid)
        {
...
}
```

THe dropdownlist displays correctly but no matter what  I select it sends 0 to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FilterProductGroupTypeId ..etc)
```

and you don't need the `Html.HiddenFor`.. just make sure everything is wrapped in a `<form>` element and when you submit that, all the values should be bound to your model (as long as you have `[HttpPost]` attribute on your receiving action